# From website form to relational database

Tags: database, data

We are putting a web form on our pre-launch site that will get responses from two types of customers. After a period, we'll need to be able to take that form data and put it into a relational database and match certain data that was collected from the two types of customers. We're not sure which database we'll use to put the form data in, but we want to make sure we don't mess up this part. The form only exports as .xls, .txt, or .csv. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: How many data You're going to collect? Do you have any prevision about?

Comment: Unless you are collecting thousands of replies a second, the database is irrelevant. BTW You are starting on the wrong foot already. That form should put the answers into the database immediately; an intermediate step with exported files takes much more work.